# IPTables on windows 10

Tags: linux, windows-10, iptables

I'm looking for a way to get iptables functionality in windows 10. any tips?

edit:
These iptables rules were used in ubuntu, when I was working on virtualizing a freeBSD with Virtualbox, with the Vbox0 Host-only Adapter Network configuration, which helped me to have an internet connection, since it forwarded packets between interfaces in the operating system, that is, it is so that my virtual machines that are in host-only have access to the internet

```
# **************  GNU/Linux ***********************
#
# 

iptables -t filter -F
iptables -t nat -F


iptables -t filter -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -P OUTPUT ACCEPT


iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I specified a little more there, thanks!